# Failed to upload files to google drive intermittently

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive API to upload files. Multiple same console app is running at the same time to upload different parts of files in the folder and their files don't overlap. This hits the quota limit. Then a while-try-catch is implemented to re-execute the query whenever it throws the exception because of the quota limit. The list and create directory method works well but not the upload (i.e. create) method. Some files are missing when i checked from the Google Drive site

Tried using FileStream instead of MemoryStream but it seems not related.

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile)
    {
        bool again = true;
        string[] p = _uploadFile.Split('/');
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:/"+_uploadFile))
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(p[p.Length-1]);
            body.Description = "";
            body.MimeType = GetMimeType("C:/"+_uploadFile);
            body.Parents = new List<string>()  { ID };


            // File's content.
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("C:/" + _uploadFile, FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Create(body, stream, GetMimeType("C:/" + _uploadFile));
                while (again)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        request.Upload();
                        again = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("uploadFile: "+p[p.Length-1]);
                    }
                }
                return body;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the message displayed when it hits your catch block?

Comment: No message. It does not hit the catch block seems

Comment: log the http  response from Drive to see what is happening.

Comment: @ssit sorry to ask, but do you know how to use a breakpoint? if yes, add breakpoint to those 2 catch block and on your else statement.. there you can get what's causing the issue. if no, add a `Console.ReadLine();` before the `return null;` and inside the inner catch block then check the message on the console app

Comment: it does not throw any exception, so the catch block is not run. By the way the problem is solved by checking the upload status, but i don't understand why it does not throw any exception when it fails.

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.